# Install zip extension for PHP --enable-zip on Mac OS X

Tags: php, linux, macos, configuration, zip

I'd like to install the following but am not sure where I should add --enable-zip? Is there more to it than putting it in php.ini ?

http://www.php.net/manual/en/zip.installation.php

Answer (score 2):

This kind of `--enable-xyz`, or `--with-xyz` are passed to the `configure` script, which is the first step (after downloading / decompressing the sources, obviously) when compiling PHP from source.

See [Installation on Unix System > Apache 2.x on Unix systems](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php) for more informations about that ; and, especialy, the part that gives an example of `configure` call :

```
10. Now, configure your PHP.  This is where you customize your PHP
    with various options, like which extensions will be enabled.  Do a
    ./configure --help for a list of available options.  In our example
    we'll do a simple configure with Apache 2 and MySQL support.  Your
    path to apxs may differ, in fact, the binary may even be named apxs2 on
    your system. 

      ./configure --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs --with-mysql
```

If you want / need to recompile PHP with that `--enable-zip option`, it'll go right in this command.